# How to use the 'Windows' or 'Super' key of ubuntu using pyautogui?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyautogui

I am tryng to automate some tasks and for that I want my **pyautogui** funtion() to press the "*windows key*" or the "*Super key*"on the **keyboard** in **Ubuntu**.
For Windows 10 and Mac OS it is predefined as '*win*' and '*command*' but what is the key name for linux to work with pyautogui?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `'winleft'` `'winright'`

I don't have Ubuntu but I checked the python file `_pyautogui_x11.py` in my python projects folder `\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui` and it gives you a list of all possible Ubuntu keys you can press.

Lines 205, 206:

```
'winleft':           _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Super_L')),
'winright':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Super_R')),
```

I noticed it's also listed [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys) at the bottom. I guess it would've made more sense to name it `'superleft'` instead of `'winleft'`

Comment: Actually I was using the same syntax but, before exeuting the cell i have to add a bit of delay using time.sleep() so that my input doesn't interferes with the program.